# How to alter the options inside element of a civicrm new membership form?

Tags: quickform

```
function custom_changes_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
if ($formName == 'CRM_Member_Form_Membership'){
  foreach($form->_elements as $key => $value){
    if ($key == 4){
    $assoc_array =  $value->_options[1][67];
      ksort($assoc_array,SORT_NUMERIC);
unset($form->_elements[$key]->_options[1][67]);
     $form->_elements[$key]->_options[1][67] = $assoc_array;
    }
  }
```

I want to alter the options order by using ksort, but I dont find any function to alter the elements like setLabel which sets label

Which is the function for altering and changing options in an element?

Comment: Why these options would be displayed in alpha order rather than in the order set in Membership Types is beyond me. I'd class that as a bug. What's the point in being able to order them if that order is not followed when displayed on a sign-up/renewal form?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

1. First get the name of the select element, and then get the elemement using this

`$element =& $form->getElement('name-of-select-element');`

i.e. don't hard code that 4.

2. You've got the options array correct, i.e. $element->_options

Now you can just replace that options like you're doing, but depending on the widget in use it can be confusing how it's structured. The one I was working on recently has option['text'] as the label. Sorting by array values can be done manually or cleverly with some php and callback functions if you're ambitious.